# Why the logrotate's bin path is `/usr/sbin`

Tags: linux, debian, logrotate

Why is the logrotate's bin path `/usr/sbin` on Debian (at least "wheezy”)
knowing that we can actually use it without the root privilege?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path for `logrotate` is placed in `/usr/sbin` likely, because it is a system administration utility which is generally executed once all filesystems are mounted.

> [logrotate(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)
>
> **logrotate** is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files.

---

> [Linux Foundation - Filesystem Hierarchy Standard - /sbin System binaries](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s16.html)
>
> Utilities used for system administration (and other root-only
>   commands) are stored in `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, and `/usr/local/sbin`.
>   `/sbin` contains binaries essential for booting, restoring,
>   recovering, and/or repairing the system in addition to the binaries in
>   /bin. **Programs executed after `/usr` is known to be mounted (when
>   there are no problems) are generally placed into `/usr/sbin`.**

Note: Many utilities in the `sbin` directories can be used by regular users.  Any user can run `ifconfig` to get information about the active network interfaces.  Of course, using `ifconfig` to modify network interface settings would require additional permissions.

Comment: I think his question is more about `bin` vs `sbin`.

Comment: `logrotate` is a system administration utility.  System administration utilities go  in `sbin`

Comment: Indeed, why couldn't one use it to rotate logs produced by a user-ran application, user-owned files. Put otherways, what in logrotate implementation makes it either unfit or insecure for non-root usage ?

Comment: OK , I read your "Note" correctly this time. the binary is indeed 755 and executable by other users. Only in sbin because it's mainly used by root I guess. Bounty credited for first and most detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

A user process can use logrotate in /usr/sbin, but only for its own logs. Root runs logrotate from cron to do it for all users. A suid bit on it is convenient, but less secure.

Comment: I haven't checked the binary file mode, indeed. Regular users can use it.